# What is the best SQL query to populate an existing column on table A with a similar column from table B?

Tags: sql, database, command, populate

Let's say I have an existing table **A** with a column called **contact_name** and a ID column **id** as the primary key.
All the rows in **A** have the **name** value as "NULL" right now.

Another table **B** has different columns, but one of which is **contact_name**, and another is **ref_id**.
Each **ref_id** in **B** corresponds to a value of **id** in **A**, and there may be multiple rows in **B** that share the same value for **ref_id** (meaning they all correspond to a single entry in **A**).

Let me set up an example:

**Table A**

```
id | contact_name
1  | [NULL]
2  | [NULL]
```

**Table B**

```
ref_id | contact_name
1      | "John"
2      | "Helen"
2      | "Alex"
```

Note there are theoretically other values in each table but for the sake of brevity I'm just showing the values I'm interested in using.

I want to populate **contact_name** in table **A** with the *first entry* of the corresponding **contact_name** in **B**, where **B.**(first)**ref_id** = **A.id**, without adding any rows or editing the rest of the rows in either table. That is, I want **A** in my example to now be:

```
id | contact_name
1  | "John"
2  | "Helen"
```

Again, note how the first **contact_name** value, "Helen", in **B** is selected, not any other subsequent one, like "Alex".

Comment: You need to have another column in TableB that uniquely specifies the order of contact_name, otherwise, there is no guarantee that 'Helen' is picked first.

Answer (score 0):

The MERGE function is made for this. Give it a try:

```
MERGE INTO TABLEA a USING (
    SELECT b.REF_ID, b.CONTACT_NAME
    FROM TABLEB) b
ON (a.ID = b.REF_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        a.CONTACT_NAME = b.CONTACT_NAME
    WHERE a.CONTACT_NAME IS null;
```

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin, which uses MYSQL and it does not recognize MERGE as a function

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Five](https://five.co/), a low-code development environment that lets you manage your MySQL database, and build a web application on top of it.

Whenever You can add a new column in a Table, Five will give you a prompt where you can use a query to populate that particular column.
Here are the steps:

1. Import your existing MySQL database into Five
2. Add a new column to your database.
3. Five will prompt you to fill in values for the new column. Five gives you four options:

   ```
       A. you can leave the new column empty,
       B. assigned a Default value,
       C. Copy Values to an existing field
       D. Write a custom query.
   ```

[Refer to This Screenshot to get an idea how things look inside Five](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkJpN.png)

Hope this helps!

**Disclaimer**: I work for Five